# Using bessel math functions from C++17 standard library in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, math, c++17

I am trying to build the following C++ code using Xcode 11.0:

```
#include <cmath>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    constexpr bool c17 = true;
    if constexpr (c17)
        double a = std::cyl_bessel_i(1.0, 2.0);
    return 0;
}
```

The function [cyl_bessel_i](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_math/cyl_bessel_i) was added to the standard library in C++17. I have set the "C++ Language Dialect" option to both c++17 and gnu++17, and in both cases the constexpr if statement compiles without warning (showing that C++17 is supported), but I get the following error:

> error: no member named 'cyl_bessel_i' in namespace 'std'

I have also tried the various alternatives suggested on the [standards page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_math/cyl_bessel_i) (__STDCPP_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__ define, tr1 namespace). In no cases could the function be found.

I was not able to find any information about whether this function is supported in Xcode online. Can you help?

Comment: I also tried to use the GCC compiler in Xcode, but couldn't get it to work. For now I'm using the boost implementation, but I would like to avoid requiring boost for this single function.

Answer (score 2):

libc++ (the standard library implementation shipped with Mac OS X) does not yet support the special math functions.